# qt pointer to qmap get value

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I have a function that needs to access the value of a qmap pointer object.

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunction(QMap<qint64, bool>* times, qint64 startPoint, qint64 endPoint)
{
    //Here I want to check the value at an existing index.
}
```

What I tried:

```
times[key];
```

and:

```
&times[key];
```

and:

```
&times[key] == 0;
```

Both give a wrong result (the value is true but i am expecting false).

[image]

Comment: for me is not clear what are those startPoint and endPoint? are those the keys? does this mean that i should iterate from startPoint to endPoint??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ those are just integers that are used as key in the map. On the riight side of the image you can see the exact type of the variables.

Comment: then you can use the "contains" method... @Sven

Answer (score 0):

in qt the qmap has a method for that: [contains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#contains)

```
times->contains(startPoint)
```

so the way to go would be:

```
if (times->contains(startPoint))
{
    ....
}
```

---

update:

to get the value of the pointer you need to be aware of the operator precedence i.e. you have to do:

```
std::map<int, bool>*x = new std::map<int, bool>();
x->insert ( std::pair<int, bool>(0,false) );
x->insert ( std::pair<int, bool>(5,true) );
bool flag = (*x)[0];
std::cout << "at 0: " << flag  << std::endl;

flag = (*x)[5];
std::cout << "at 5: " << flag << std::endl;
```

so in your case

```
bool flag = (*times)[startPoint];
```

Comment: contains returns true if the key exist, not the actual value of the map at key. I want to get the value of the map where the key is a specific value.

Comment: ok... now i see where are you having problems with... use the ***bool flag = (*times)[startPoint];***

Comment: please see my update and let me know... @SvenvandenBoogaart